# How can Excel open a .txt file and keep 0x0D chars and foreign chars ß ä?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How can Excel open a .txt file and keep 0x0D chars and foreign chars ß ä? The file is tab delimited.

Windows 7, Excel 2010

---

Edited ten minutes later.

I drag and drop one .txt file and it works fine.  I drag and drop a second .txt file and it does not.

The second .txt file appears to be a different encoding.  They both display fine with NotePad.

Comment: That's simply UTF-8 isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways

1) Open Microsoft Excel then drag&drop .txt file it will ask for field seperator etc.

2) Import from datasource follow the link below

https://support.office.com/en-IE/article/Connect-to-a-Text-file-5d571c3a-3b05-43c5-9f7d-54d17a8557cb